# Don't know how to do it with Javascript and maybe html + css

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have made a popup with text an img. It works when i only have ''Biografi'', but when i add ''Contact'' i don't know how to make it possible with the javascript to have 2 different popup of both ''Biografi and ''Contact''. Can someone pls help me with this pls? Because when i click ''Biografi'' the same comes up as if i would have clicked ''Contact''

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            btn.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                  modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
            
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

            btn.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                  modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
```

```css
              .text4 > a {
                text-decoration: underline;
                text-decoration-color: #fad184;
                text-decoration-style: dotted;
                color: #fad184;
              }

              .text4 > a:hover {
                opacity: 0.7;
              }

              .modal {
              display: none;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 1;
              padding-top: 100px;
              left: 0;
              top: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              overflow: auto;
              background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            }

            .modal-content {
              position: relative;
              background-color: brown;
              color: #fad184;
              font-family: verdana;
              margin: auto;
              padding: 0;
              border: 1px solid #fff;
              width: 80%;
              box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
              -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
              -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
              animation-name: animatetop;
              animation-duration: 0.4s
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
              from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
              to {top:0; opacity:1}
            }

            @keyframes animatetop {
              from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
              to {top:0; opacity:1}
            }

            .close {
              color: #fad184;
              float: right;
              font-size: 28px;
              font-weight: bold;
              margin-right: 10px;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
              color: #000;
              text-decoration: none;
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            .modal-header {
              padding: 2px 16px;
              background-color: brown;
              color: #fad184;
            }

            .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

            .modal-footer {
              padding: 2px 16px;
              background-color: brown;
              color: #fad184;
            }
```

```html
<div class="div5">
  <p id="myBtn" class="text4"><a href="#">Biografi</a></p>
  <p id="myBtn1" class="text4"><a href="#">Contact</a></p>
  <p class="text4"><a href="#">hey</a></p>
  <p class="text4"><a href="#">hey</a></p>
  <p class="text4"><a href="#">hey</a></p>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="div1">
                <div class="close1">&times;</div>
                  <div class="div2" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="div11">
                      <div class="div13">
                        <img src="ungeferrari1.jpg" class="img3">
                      </div>
                      <div class="div12">
                        <div style="margin-left:15px">
                          <p class="textbio1">Biografi:</p>
                          <p class="textbio2">25-åringen Unge Ferrari aka Stig J. Haugen er en norsk rapper fra Hamar i Norge.
                            Han vokste opp i et vanekslig miljø.
                          Som 8 åring begynte han å fatte interesse for rapping og starter og preformer i en alder av 16 år.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="div1">
                <div class="close">&times;</div>
                  <div class="div2" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="div11">
                      <div class="div13">
                        <img src="ungeferrari1.jpg" class="img3">
                      </div>
                      <div class="div12">
                        <div style="margin-left:15px">
                          <p class="textbio1">Biografi:</p>
                          <p class="textbio2">25-åringen Unge Ferrari aka Stig J. Haugen er en norsk rapper fra Hamar i Norge.
                            Han vokste opp i et vanekslig miljø.
                          Som 8 åring begynte han å fatte interesse for rapping og starter og preformer i en alder av 16 år.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? You do know that Java is something entirely different from JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems.

The main things I fixed to get this working:

1. In both sets of handlers you referred to the `modal` variable-- as that variable can only been one thing at one time.  As such, I instead encapsulated both button setups in functions to encapsulate a local `modal` `var` assignment
2. You had duplicate content in both modals, so you wouldn't have been able to tell the difference regardless
3. You had swapped the close buttons between the two modals.

Additionally, you really need to rethink your naming conventions for classes and IDs.  Simply numbering them `div1`, `div2`, etc has *zero* semantic meaning-- it won't scale or maintain easily, nor will it be easy to remember if you leave and come back to it.  Instead, try classing and id-ing for what things *are* and *do* -- *semantic naming*.

Finally, please remember that Java and JavaScript are different, unrelated languages. :)  Good luck!

```js
function setupFirstBtn() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function setupSecondBtn () { 
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

  btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}

setupFirstBtn();
setupSecondBtn();
```

```css
.text4 > a {
                text-decoration: underline;
                text-decoration-color: #fad184;
                text-decoration-style: dotted;
                color: #fad184;
              }

              .text4 > a:hover {
                opacity: 0.7;
              }

              .modal {
              display: none;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 1;
              padding-top: 100px;
              left: 0;
              top: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              overflow: auto;
              background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            }

            .modal-content {
              position: relative;
              background-color: brown;
              color: #fad184;
              font-family: verdana;
              margin: auto;
              padding: 0;
              border: 1px solid #fff;
              width: 80%;
              box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
              -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
              -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
              animation-name: animatetop;
              animation-duration: 0.4s
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
              from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
              to {top:0; opacity:1}
            }

            @keyframes animatetop {
              from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
              to {top:0; opacity:1}
            }

            .close {
              color: #fad184;
              float: right;
              font-size: 28px;
              font-weight: bold;
              margin-right: 10px;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
              color: #000;
              text-decoration: none;
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            .modal-header {
              padding: 2px 16px;
              background-color: brown;
              color: #fad184;
            }

            .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

            .modal-footer {
              padding: 2px 16px;
              background-color: brown;
              color: #fad184;
            }
```

```html
<div class="div5">
  <p id="myBtn" class="text4"><a href="#">Biografi</a></p>
  <p id="myBtn1" class="text4"><a href="#">Contact</a></p>
  <p class="text4"><a href="#">hey</a></p>
  <p class="text4"><a href="#">hey</a></p>
  <p class="text4"><a href="#">hey</a></p>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="div1">
                <div class="close">&times;</div>
                  <div class="div2" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="div11">
                      <div class="div13">
                        <img src="ungeferrari1.jpg" class="img3">
                      </div>
                      <div class="div12">
                        <div style="margin-left:15px">
                          <p class="textbio1">Biografi:</p>
                          <p class="textbio2">25-åringen Unge Ferrari aka Stig J. Haugen er en norsk rapper fra Hamar i Norge.
                            Han vokste opp i et vanekslig miljø.
                          Som 8 åring begynte han å fatte interesse for rapping og starter og preformer i en alder av 16 år.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="div1">
                <div class="close1">&times;</div>
                  <div class="div2" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="div11">
                      <div class="div13">
                        <img src="ungeferrari1.jpg" class="img3">
                      </div>
                      <div class="div12">
                        <div style="margin-left:15px">
                          <p class="textbio1">CONTACT:</p>
                          <p class="textbio2">CONTACTCONTACTCONTACT</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```